# Linked List - Stack Sorting in C

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

My code is following:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

struct stack {
    int data;
    struct stack* next;
};
struct Student
{
    unsigned long int rollnumber;
    char name[100];
    struct Student *next;
    
}* head;
// Utility function to initialize stack
void initStack(struct stack** s) { *s = NULL; }
 
// Utility function to check if stack is empty
int isEmpty(struct stack* s)
{
    if (s == NULL)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
 
// Utility function to push an item to stack
void push(struct stack** s, int x, unsigned long int rollnumber, char *name)
{
    struct stack* p = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(*p));
 
    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed.\n");
        return;
    }
 
    p->data = x;
    p->next = *s;
    *s = p;
}
 
// Utility function to remove an item from stack
int pop(struct stack** s)
{
    int x;
    struct stack* temp;
 
    x = (*s)->data;
    temp = *s;
    (*s) = (*s)->next;
    free(temp);
 
    return x;
}

// Function to find top item
int top(struct stack* s) { return (s->data); }

// Recursive function to insert an item x in sorted way
void sortedInsert(struct stack** s, int x, unsigned long int rollnumber, char *name)
{
    // Base case: Either stack is empty or newly inserted
    // item is less than top (more than all existing)
    if (isEmpty(*s) || x < top(*s)) {
        push(s, x, rollnumber, name);
        return;
    }
    else{
    // If top is less, remove the top item and recur
    int temp = pop(s);
    sortedInsert(s, x, rollnumber, name);
 
    // Put back the top item removed earlier
    push(s, temp, rollnumber, name);}
}
 
// Function to sort stack
void sortStack(struct stack** s)
{
    // If stack is not empty
    char *name;
    unsigned long int rollnumber;
    if (!isEmpty(*s)) {
        // Remove the top item
        int x = pop(s);
 
        // Sort remaining stack
        sortStack(s);
 
        // Push the top item back in sorted stack
        sortedInsert(s, x, rollnumber, name);
    }
}
// Utility function to print contents of stack
void printStack(struct stack* s, unsigned long int rollnumber, char* name)
{
    struct Student* student = (struct Student *) malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
    struct Student* temp = head;
    while (s && temp!=NULL) {
        printf("%lu %s\n", temp->rollnumber, temp->name);
        s = s->next;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void insert(unsigned long int rollnumber, char* name)
{
    
    struct Student * student = (struct Student *) malloc(sizeof(struct Student));
    student->rollnumber = rollnumber;
    strcpy(student->name, name);
    student->next = NULL;
    
    if(head==NULL){
        // if head is NULL
        // set student as the new head
        head = student;
    }
    else{
        // if list is not empty
        // insert student in beginning of head
        student->next = head;
        head = student;
    }
    
}

void Delete(unsigned long int rollnumber)
{
    struct Student * temp1 = head;
    struct Student * temp2 = head; 
    while(temp1!=NULL){
        
        if(temp1->rollnumber==rollnumber){
            
            printf("Record with roll number %lu Found\n", rollnumber);
            
            if(temp1==temp2){
                // this condition will run if
                // the record that we need to delete is the first node
                // of the linked list
                head = head->next;
                free(temp1);
            }
            else{
                // temp1 is the node we need to delete
                // temp2 is the node previous to temp1
                temp2->next = temp1->next;
                free(temp1); 
            }
            
            printf("Record successfully deleted\n");
            return;
            
        }
        temp2 = temp1;
        temp1 = temp1->next;
        
    }
printf("Student with roll number %lu is not found\n", rollnumber);
    
}
void display()
{
    struct Student * temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        
        printf("Roll Number: %lu\n", temp->rollnumber);
        printf("Name: %s\n", temp->name);
        temp = temp->next;
        
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    head = NULL;
    int choice;
    int fc_,id_,year_, fc_year;
    char name[100];
    struct student* s;
    unsigned long int rollnumber;
    struct stack* faculty;
    struct stack* year;
    struct stack* id;
    initStack(&faculty);
    initStack(&year);
    initStack(&id);
    printf("1 - Enter school number\n2 - Display school numbers by ID\n3 - Display school numbers sorted by year\n4 - Display school numbers sorted by the faculty codes\n5 - Delete a record by school number\n6 - Exit");
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter Choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Enter roll number: ");
                scanf("%lu", &rollnumber);
                fc_ = rollnumber/pow(10, 6);
                id_ = rollnumber%(10*10*10*10);
                fc_year = rollnumber/pow(10,4);
                year_ = fc_year%(100);
                printf("Enter name: ");
                scanf("%s", name);
                insert(rollnumber, name);
                push(&faculty, fc_, rollnumber, name);
                push(&year, year_, rollnumber, name);
                push(&id, id_, rollnumber, name);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Sorted by ID: \n");
                sortStack(&id);
                printStack(id, rollnumber, name);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Sorted by year: \n");
                sortStack(&year);
                printStack(year, rollnumber, name);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Sorted by faculty code: \n");
                sortStack(&faculty);
                printStack(faculty, rollnumber, name);
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("Enter roll number to delete: ");
                scanf("%lu", &rollnumber);
                Delete(rollnumber);
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
        }
        
    } while (choice != 6);
}
```

When, for example, the choice is 2, I want to display the student name and whole rollnumber in ascending order. But when I run it that is what I get (C, B, A are the names given by me):

```
Enter Choice: 2
705102020 C
705102010 B
705102005 A
```

I am sure that I sorted it correctly, but probably my printStack function is not working properly. How can I reverse this?

Comment: `pop()` and `top()` functions don't handle the case of a null pointer.

Comment: Your `sortStack()` function declares local variables `name` and `rollnumber`, and then it passes them to `sortedInsert()` without ever assigning values to them.  Undefined behavior results.

Comment: If it is the case, why is it sorted in descending order? It shouldn't have been sorted at all. @JohnBollinger

Comment: @goku Undefined behavior can result in a _seemingly_ working program.

Comment: First time I've seen that @Zakk

Comment: Learn to use your debugging tools and step through the process.

Comment: Is this an actual help? It is like saying "learn how to code". Alright I try that @LeeTaylor

Comment: @goku Learning to use your debugging tools and debugging in general is one of most important skills to have as a coder. It's something that can only come from practice and doing.

Comment: Yes, @goku, it *is* actual help, even if not the kind you were looking for.  Debugger use is an essential development skill.

Comment: @goku, how exactly do you think `sortedInsert()` is performing any sorting?  I don't see any comparisons of node contents.

Comment: It compares top element with the data @JohnBollinger

Comment: And assumption made here is that I did not try to debug that. Keep in mind that I asked this question because I've spent a good amount of time on it, yet could not manage to succeed. That is why I asked the question itself. I am a student in electrical engineering, not a professional coder. I ask to learn, that is all. So sorry, but this is not actual help @JohnBollinger

Comment: @goku "_The first 3 digits are faculty code, the other 2 digits are the year, and the last 4 digits are ID._" Okay, but what if the faculty code is 2 digit long? Or the ID is 3 digit long?

Comment: I can raise an error in that case. By default, rollnumbers are 9 digits.  And these 9 digits are parsed into 3-2-4 digits indicating their relative code. @Zakk

Comment: @goku For example, what if the faculty code is `10`? And why don't you use a `char[10]`?

Comment: If I used char, I would have to concatenate numbers. For example, 705 would be char[0}-char[1]-char[2].  And I would have to atoi() the rollnumber. I think using strings is more cumbersome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to define a stack struct independantly of the rest of your code:

```c
struct stack {
    void *data;
    struct stack *next;
};

void stack_init(struct stack **ss)
{
    *ss = NULL;
}

bool stack_push(struct stack **ss, void *data)
{
    struct stack *node = malloc(sizeof *node);
    if (!node) return false;
    
    node->data = data; // Copy address, not data
    node->next = *ss;
    *ss = node;
    
    return true;
}

bool stack_pop(struct stack **ss, void **data)
{
    if (!*ss) return false;
    
    struct stack *rm = *ss;
    *ss = (*ss)->next;
    if (data) *data = rm->data; // If nothing is provided (i.e. NULL), data will leak if it was allocated dynamically.
    free(rm);
    
    return true;
}

bool stack_top(const struct stack *ss, void **data)
{
    if (!ss) return false;
    
    *data = ss->data;
    return true;
}

void stack_print(const struct stack *ss, void print(const struct stack*))
{
    for (const struct stack *sp = ss; sp; sp = sp->next)
        print(sp);
}
```

You can implement your stack sorting function like that:

```c
struct stack *stack_find_min(struct stack *ss, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
    struct stack *min = ss;
    for (struct stack *sp = ss; sp; sp = sp->next)
        if (cmp(sp->data, min->data) < 0)
            min = sp;
    
    return min;
}

void stack_sort(struct stack *ss, int (*cmp)(const void*, const void*))
{
    if (!ss) return;
    
    for (struct stack *sp = ss; sp; sp = sp->next) {
        struct stack *min = stack_find_min(sp, cmp);
        swap(&sp->data, &min->data);
    }
}
```

`swap()` swaps two pointers:

```c
void swap(void **p1, void **p2)
{
    void *tmp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = tmp;
}
```

After that, define your student data structure:

```c
struct student {
    unsigned long rollnumber;
    char name[100];
    struct student *next;
};

struct student *student_insert(struct student **head, unsigned long rollnumber, const char *name)
{
    struct student *st = malloc(sizeof(*st));
    if (!st) return NULL;
    
    st->rollnumber = rollnumber;
    strncpy(st->name, name, 99);
    st->next = *head;
    *head = st;
    
    return st;
}

void student_print(const struct stack *ss)
{
    struct student *st = ss->data;
    printf("%ld\t%s\n", st->rollnumber, st->name);
}

int student_compare_id(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
    // MUST cast void* into (struct student*) first.
    const struct student *student1 = s1;
    const struct student *student2 = s2;
    
    unsigned long rollnumber1 = student1->rollnumber;
    unsigned long rollnumber2 = student2->rollnumber;
    
    unsigned long id1 = rollnumber1 % 10000;
    unsigned long id2 = rollnumber2 % 10000;
    
    return id1 == id2 ? 0 : (id1 < id2 ? -1 : 1);
}
```

If you want to test the above:

```c
int main(void)
{
    struct stack *ss;
    stack_init(&ss);

    struct student *st = NULL;
    student_insert(&st, 100181234, "James");
    student_insert(&st, 200195678, "John");
    student_insert(&st, 300200324, "Goku");
    student_insert(&st, 400214321, "Taylor");
    
    for (struct student *p = st; p; p = p->next)
        stack_push(&ss, p);

    puts("Unsorted stack:");    
    stack_print(ss, student_print);
    
    stack_sort(ss, student_compare_id);
    
    puts("\nSorted by ID:");
    stack_print(ss, student_print);

    // Don't forget to free the memory allocated for students
    // and pop all nodes of the stack (ommited here).
}
```

Output:

```txt
Unsorted stack:
100181234   James
200195678   John
300200324   Goku
400214321   Taylor

Sorted by ID:
300200324   Goku
100181234   James
400214321   Taylor
200195678   John
```

---

Few more things:

- Don't use `scanf()` to read user input. [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is safer.
- You can replace `pow(10, 4)` directly by `10000`. Why wasting CPU cycles to calculate constants?
- In your `insert()` function, there is no need to test for `*head == NULL`. The code in the else statement handles this case.

---

**EDIT:** In `student_compare_id()`, the `const void*` pointers MUST BE CASTED to `const struct student*` first before dereferencing. The previous version *seemed* to work because the rollnumber happened to be the first field in the struct. That was an undefined behavior in all its glory. Fixed that now.

Here is the previous version that **NO ONE SHOULD USE:**

```c
int student_compare_id(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
    unsigned long rollnumber1 = *(unsigned long*)s1; // WRONG!
    unsigned long rollnumber2 = *(unsigned long*)s2; // WRONG!
    
    unsigned long id1 = rollnumber1 % 10000;
    unsigned long id2 = rollnumber2 % 10000;
    
    return id1 == id2 ? 0 : (id1 < id2 ? -1 : 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that really does solve the issue. One thing though, this code compiles but gives me a bunch of errors, more than 10 maybe.  For example: 
note: expected 'struct student**' but argument is of type 'struct strudent **
'
 Expected student** but argument of type student**? Why is this an error given you have passed the same type?

Comment: @goku Yes. In fact, it was caused by a typo: `struct strudent *st = NULL;` instead of `struct student *st = NULL;` (note the `r`). Fixed that.

Comment: @goku Also, changed `const char name[100]` to `const char *name` in `student_insert()`.

Comment: @goku Now, it compiles without warnings. Btw, "_this code compiles but gives me a bunch of errors..._" Those are warnings, not errors. A code doesn't compile if it has errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Yep I fixed that too. Just a quick question
- Why is fgets() safer than scanf() since they basically read only the input
- About parsing the number, which one makes more sense? Accepting the rollnumber as a string and manipulate it, then use atoi(), or accepting it as an integer than doing the same?

Comment: It compiles when it has logic errors

Comment: @goku For why `fgets()` is safer than `scanf()`, I suggest you read [this](https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: @goku About parsing the number, guess it's better to use a string. Because, for example,  the faculty number could be `10`, which clearly has not 3 digits. With a string, you can pad it with 0.

Comment: @goku "_It compiles when it has logic errors_". I mean compile-time errors.

Comment: Got it, I will try strings. 
That was very helpful, I appreciate it.

Comment: @goku Please read the edit above.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please? We have talked before about **seemingly working codes**. What do you mean by it worked because it was the first field in the struct? @Zakk

Comment: And little typo, there should be two students so its student2

Comment: @goku Fixed the typo. Thanks.

Comment: @goku If you have a struct like this: `struct object {long num; char name[100]};`, and a pointer to that struct: `struct object obj = {10, "something"}; void *p = &obj;`, doing `long lg = *(long*)p;` _can_ result in accessing the first field of the struct (since a pointer to a struct is a pointer to its first field). However, compilers may re-order the fields internally, thus the previous version had UB.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the edit

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem is that there is no connection between your stack(s) and your student list, but the code assumes that there is.  You can reorder the stacks however you like, but that does not reorder the list.  When you print, the students simply come out in the reverse of their insertion order (because you insert at the front of the list, and then traverse the list from front to back).

You have two main alternatives:

1. combine the list and all the stacks into one linked list.  You can use this both list-style and stack-style if you like.  OR
2. Give the stack nodes pointers to the corresponding list elements, and traverse those when you print a stack to get the students in the order implied by the stack.

Comment: Alternative 2 seems more flexible. He can implement a stack independantly from the list.

Comment: In practice, @Zakk, analogues of both approaches are used in problems similar to this one, depending on the circumstances.  Alternative (1) is more robust, and it is often sufficient.  Alternative (2) offers more flexibility -- maintaining multiple sort orders at the same time, for example -- but it is more complex and more brittle, especially in the face of data modifications.

Comment: I have implemented Alternative (2). It is not that complex. Moreover, it allows reusability of both data structures (i.e. stack and student, though student is less likely to be reused).

Comment: @Zakk, I have implemented both alternatives, many times each.  The main problem with alternative (2) is not the complexity of adding a level of indirection, but the added complexity that it requires elsewhere in the program, such as when students are added or (especially) deleted.  As for reusability, that tends to be a more attractive argument in theory than is warranted by real-world practice.  Except if you're specifically writing a reusable library -- and designing appropriately for that -- the likelihood of actual reuse is usually small.

Comment: "_Except if you're specifically writing a reusable library_" That's what I did in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71887461/16835308).

Comment: "_the likelihood of actual reuse is usually small._" Yes. This is the case for student struct.